# UISearchBar with UISearchController at the top of the UIViewController breaks when tapping on it

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm using `UISearchController` with its `UISearchBar`.

I'd like to put `UISearchBar` at the top of my `UIViewController`'s view using AutoLayout:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    let myCustomSearchBar = UISearchBar()

    var searchBar: UISearchBar {
        // return searchController.searchBar
        return myCustomSearchBar
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        view.addSubview(searchBar)
        configureSearchBarLayout()
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    private func configureSearchBarLayout() {
        [
            searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor),
            searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 88)
            ]
            .forEach{
                $0.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in the following view being displayed:

[image]

However, as soon as I tap on the searhBar, it moves out of the screen completely to never reappear again.

If I modify the code to include a basic `UISearchBar`, not created by the `UISearchController`, it works fine:

[image]

**Why does the `UISearchController`'s SearchBar doesn't work correctly when I try to snap it to the top with AutoLayout and how to fix it?**

Comment: https://openradar.appspot.com/17315600

Comment: @ElTomato What is the correct usage then?